# link an old app user to a facebook account using parse always fail

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to link an existing account in my app to a facebook account, but the parameter succeed in the parse API always return false (no error) I am able to use the API to create a new user, post and read the user information etc, but when I try to link the accounts using the code below it always fail:

```
func facebook(user: PFUser){
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"])
    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            println("error requesting FBSDKGraphRequest \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else{
            let userData = result as! NSDictionary
            println(userData)
            let facebookID = userData["id"] as! String
            user.username = userData["name"] as? String
            if let email = userData["email"] as? String{

                //find user email on facebook
                user.email = email

                if let checkForUser = CreateConnection.findUserByEmail(email){

                    //find PFUser that have that email
                    println("find a match for old user on facebook")
                    if !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(checkForUser) {

                        //the PFUser that has the email is not already linked with facebook
                        PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(checkForUser, withReadPermissions: nil,  block: {
                            //link account in the background
                            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                             //no error return
                             if let error = error{
                                println("error linking user to facebook \(error.localizedDescription) ")
                            }
                            //succeeded return false
                            if succeeded  {
                                println("the user is now linked with Facebook!")
                            } else{
                                //this line is printed
                                println("link did not succeeded")

                            }
                        })
                    }
                } else{
                   //code to create a new account here
                }
```

This is what I have in appDelegate:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
}
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

Another strange behaviour I notice is that the facebook screen to authorize the app popup twice, once as soon as you click login with facebook as expected and once as soon as the debugger hits the end of the block linkUserInBackground (before even go inside yet)

Answer (score 0):

Only Authenticated user can edit their own data. A User cannot edit another User, not even through ACLs. 
I think only solution is to use Cloud Function with Master Key. https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code